# ¿Por qué llamamos padrastros a las tirillas de piel cerca de las uñas?

Tags: etimología

Del DRAE (como todos sabemos)

> [padrastro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RQdBfrY)
>
> 4. m. Pedazo pequeño de pellejo que se levanta de la carne inmediata a las uñas de las manos, y causa dolor y estorbo.

Es cierto que la tercera acepción es

> 3. m. Obstáculo, impedimento o inconveniente que estorba o hace daño en una materia.

No sé si la tercera ha propiciado la cuarta o si ha sido al revés. Entiendo que los padrastros de nuestra uñas a veces son un estorbo, pero no siempre.

En cualquier caso, la etimología de padrastro viene del latín "*pater*". Por supuesto que de ahí salen las primeras acepciones de "Marido de la madre de una persona nacida de una unión anterior de aquella" y "Mal padre".

Entiendo que tanto para los padrastros como para las [madrastras](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NprrOog), se asume que tratan mal a sus hijos putativos, y de ahí esas segundas acepciones.

Sería fácil asumir que a los pellejos de las manos les llamamos padrastros porque "estorban" en la vida, como un padrastro o madrastra, pero ¿es esa la razón real o hay más en la etimología de "padrastro"?

¿Puede alguien confirmar la etimología de padrastro para referirse a las tirillas de piel cerca de las uñas?

Comment: Pienso que esto necesita una etiqueta de región. Nunca antes había oído ese nombre para lo que yo siempre he conocido como **uñero** y no creo que nadie en Colombia lo reconozca

Comment: Interesante. Creo que la diferencia, por lo menos en España, es que el [uñero](https://dle.rae.es/?id=b7CnVTh), como dice el DRAE, es una infección donde la uña toca la carne, mientras que el padrastro es una tirilla de piel, normalmente encima de las uñas. Si confirma la gente que en otros países estos términos se usan de forma distinta, le pondré la etiqueta a la pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Desde luego, *estorbo* fue la palabra que usó Covarrubias en 1611 cuando definió lo que era un padrastro. Os pongo su definición completa para que podáis entenderla en su integridad (negritas mías):

> PADRASTRO, el segundo marido, que en respeto de los hijos del primer matrimonio que se llaman antenados, [...] se llamò padrastro por suceder al padre [...]. Padrastro, el estorvo y el impedimento, que tiene alguna fuerça, o villa, o ciudad, de donde sobreviniendo enemigos pueden ser ofendidos dellos. **Dixose assi porque les está siempre delante de los ojos, como amenaçandoles: aludiendo al recelo que tiene el antenado de que su padrastro si puede le hará daño.**

En 1737 el *Autoridades* define ya *padrastro* con la acepción de "pedacito de pellejo", pero no explica el porqué de dicho significado. Entiendo que ese tipo de padrastro se corresponden también con un "estorbo o impedimiento". En todo caso, en 1620 ya se encuentran textos como este:

> *Dificultoso será que de todo punto quiera él desasirse del gobierno desta casa como quien tantos años ha gozado pacífica posesión, pero lo que se podrá hacer es encargalle, porque lo deseó mucho en vida de mi padre, aunque él no hizo buen rostro a esta petición por no apartalle de su lado, el hacienda que mi hermano tiene dos leguas de Cuenca y con título de Alcaide del castillo y jurisdicción sobre las dos aldeas, que todas estas tijeras son menester para cortar un padrastro tan duro.*