# ¿Por qué llamamos abuelos/abuelillos a los mechoncitos que quedan sueltos en la nuca?

Tags: etimología

Hace tiempo pregunté [¿Por qué llamamos padrastros a las tirillas de piel cerca de las uñas?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31486/5481) y su relación con "estorbo o impedimento", y resultó que había cierta relación entre el "pedacito de pellejo", "estorbo" y el estereotipo del mal padrastro ("Marido de la madre de una persona nacida de una unión anterior de aquella").

Otra que estaba en mis lista es "abuelillo", definido en el DRAE en la entrada de "[abuelo](https://dle.rae.es/abuelo)" como

> 4. m. Cada uno de los mechoncitos que quedan sueltos en la nuca cuando se atiranta el cabello hacia arriba. U. m. en pl.

¿Por qué llamamos "abuelillos (o abuelos)" a los mechoncillos sueltos del pelo de la nuca? ¿Es, al igual que con la pregunta de los padrastros, algo tan simple como que los abuelos tienen abuelillos? Cabría destacar que no solo los abuelos tienen abuelillos.

¿Cuál es la etimología de esa cuarta acepción de "abuelo?

Comment: Antes de terminar de leer ya estaba pensando en los padrastros y también recordé que a las líneas que quedan aisladas de un párrafo impreso porque el resto del párrafo está en otra página (anterior o posterior) se las llama "viudas" y "huérfanas". Hay algo para estudiar ahí. :)

Comment: @pablodf76 trivia: en alemán, a esas líneas "viudas" se las llama "[Hurenkind(er)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurenkind_und_Schusterjunge)", que significa "hija(s) de #@!*". Ahí sí que tienen algo que estudiar...

Comment: @wimi Es la bronca del que tiene que componer la página.

Comment: Quizás porque son los únicos mechones que le quedan a algunos en la nunca cuando son abuelos. Lo del padrasto de las uñas es de uso común, pero esto de los abuellillos en la nuca, no lo había escuchado nunca. Quizás porque nunca fue una de mis preocupaciones cómo se me quedaría el cogote si me hiciera una coleta, quién sabe ....  :)

Answer (score 1):

Nunca había escuchado el término, sin embargo buscando, encontré las siguientes posibilidades:

- Similar a la respuesta de Fran, quizá te das cuenta que existen hasta que eres mayor o porque sobresalen más siendo adulto.
- Los abuelos tienden a ser pocos y sobresalen en las familias.